# Diablo 3: Question about alternative gear choices

Tags: diablo-iii

http://www.diablofans.com/builds/69830-2-4-fastest-torment-10-build-ue-fire

My gear is not prefect yet and there is lot of room to improve.

For the 10 torment unhallowed essence set build linked earlier, I am looking for suggestion to alternative gear choices.

Ever since we have cosmetic pets that can pick up. I decide to move my build away from synergy with gold pickup somewhat.

My current gear stand as this: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Plaguebone-1428/hero/1979730

Staying alive isn't a problem at least for me.

Is there a better gear with respect to either more damage or utility for kanai armor cube effect and better belt choice?

I am NOT going to use pickup radius and moving away from that component of the diablo fan build linked. I don't plan to use goldwrap either as well. SO keep that in mind.

Comment: Why the down vote? Hunter's wrath deal more damage on primary skills, Witching hour deal more critical damage but attack speed is wasted here, vigilante belt is nice and let you drop cdr on some item for other attribute. There are far too many kanai armor cube alternative to list in comment.

Comment: The problem is probably because nobody can figure out whether this is a question.

Comment: Two questions. Is there a better alternative gear or effect to use to replace nemesis bracer in kanai's cube (moved to bracer slot) and better belt choice since I am not focusing on pickup radius.

Comment: I suppose you could try making that more apparent, such as stating that clearer in the title. If people don't see a question, they won't bother answering.

Comment: Another problem with this is it is up to playstyle and personal preference. Both would make this question opinion based and not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Hypothetically, would this be less opinion-based if the question was requesting things that meet a certain criteria, i.e. "better for a certain playstyle"? Seems like it could salvage this question.

Comment: The playstyle is either killing faster or more utility. Not much else you need with this build as I can two shot torment high hp 10 white mobs. I also edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: It could help or it could end up being too localized to this specific build. To try and provide some help for the question though, the obvious answer is to try and find a goldwrap since that is the belt listed for this build. But since that's the piece you're missing then try finding a piece with similar stats, or provides bonuses to compliment other gear choices or cover up any weaknesses you might have. One would need more information to answer such as are you lacking damage? Dying too easily? Just want to move and farm faster?

Comment: I don't plan to get a goldwrap. I am mostly trying to find a decent ancient belt to replace the one I have current and find a better damage or more utility out of my kanai's armor cube piece. Yes I know my amulet isn't ideal but I plan to work on that eventually.

Comment: I made a few more edits so look it over again.

Comment: So looking at your gear, you need better everything to pull this build off. You need, repeat, NEED, 37% CDR to make the build viable. That's where your Hatred issues are coming from. You need more crit, and you need to roll off all those +% skills. That damage roll on your HF needs to be +%Fire. With speed running builds, you can't just slap the pieces together and expect to clear T10 in 2 mins. The gear needs to be high quality, too. Goldwrap really is, mechanically, the best belt for this build. Anything else might not work at all.

Comment: @Dallium Not helping this is a fairly new build and I am still working on pieces. I don't need "prefect build" yet. Heck my cosmetic pet can pick up gold like 4-5 vault away and still in screen (across a chasm). So pickup gold radius is kind of silly considering the pets' pickup radius. I am not going for "speed t10" speed yet.

Comment: Look, I don't know what to tell you. You haven't discovered something that the people who have played this game for years and spend 40+ hours a week theory crafting have missed. Avarice band is not only not silly but mandatory for builds of this kind.

Comment: Did I ask for a torment 10 alternative choices? No I did not. I just replaced my amulet with a better one that has 10% cc + dex. The earlier one had zero damage and had to be reroll to include more raw damage. Nevermind the nemesis bracer that had 19% physical type damage bonus for an earlier build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as belts go, [Harrington WaistGuard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/harrington-waistguard) and [the Witching Hour](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-witching-hour) both provide the largest damage boosts compared to other belts. If you use primary skills often you can [Hunter's Wrath](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hunters-wrath) as well. [Cord of the Sherma](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/cord-of-the-sherma) and [Omryn's Chain](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/omryns-chain) provide some defensive utility bonuses.

For Armor bonuses in Kanai's cube it probably is up to personal preference so I will just list possibilities and the bonuses they give. You said you have no trouble staying alive so I did not include anything that gives defensive bonuses

- [Pride's Fall](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/prides-fall) Provides resource cost reduction when not taking damage.
- [Cindercoat](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/cindercoat) Provides constant resource cost redution for fire skills (multishot in your case)
- [Warzechian Armguards](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/warzechian-armguards) Give large movement speed bonuses any time you destroy a breakable object, this could help with clear speed in areas with lots of breakables since multishot will be hitting everything.
- [Reaper's Wraps](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/reapers-wraps) Give primary resource when picking up health globes. These have the bonus of being craftable once you get the plans from Malthael.
- [Hexing Pants of Mr. Yan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hexing-pants-of-mr-yan) Gives resource regen and damage bonuses while moving.
- [Depth Diggers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/depth-diggers) Give a large damage boost to primary skills

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason every T10 farming build works in gold wrap; between Avarice band and BotH, there is always gold, and gold = speed. So when you throw in gold wrap, gold ALSO = toughness. So much toughness that you can sacrifice toughness rolls on all your other gear, because you're running around with hundreds of thousands of armor. Which means more dps across your gear. By dropping gold wrap, you need to have a lot more toughness on the rest of your gear. Basically, that one affix boosts your DPS indirectly by meeting all your toughness needs.

Secondly, any build that relies on hitting a CDR breakpoint to keep a buff up all the time (like any Dawn-cubing DH or Boomsader) should have a diamond in the helm. If you hit the breakpoint without the diamond, roll CDR off your gear. The diamond is nonnegotiable. CDR stacks multiplicatively, so that 12.5% is a better investment than two 6% rolls (which could be a Crit stat, AD or IAS). Besides, the only other worthwhile gem is the Amethyst, and you don't need anymore toughness.

Thirdly, almost every speed running build wants Nemesis bracers and  Warzechian Wristguards. Wear one and cube the other, unless your build has some really specific items that outweigh more progress orbs and faster movement speed. (As an aside, if you're a UE DH with hatred problems, you aren't doing enough damage, but feel free to fill in with a Cidercoat or Pride's Fall while you wait for some ancients) Ditch the Custerians, they stop being worthwhile long before you can speed run T10; even if you gain 100M gold in a rift (which you probably won't), that barely dents a paragon level past 600 and you'd get more running GRifts anyway.

Look, play the game your way, but gold wrap's one stop toughness sink is pretty much what makes speed running viable. I've used the exact build you've linked for awhile now and my average clear time is 2.5 minutes, depending on the rift, with half ancients.